Why aren't we using forward swept wings in commercial airliners?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing so.
Is there any practical problem in execution?
Provide some experiments for examples.

Does this answer your question?

Related: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4306/7532
